Counting 1-row extensions to Latin Rectangles
A Latin rectangle is a $k\times{n}$ matrix with $n$ symbols and with no symbol appearing more than once in each row or column. Clearly, $k\leq n$. Let's assume that the symbols are the numbers $0,1,\dots,n-1$. The rectangle is called normalized if the first row is in natural order from $0$ to $n-1$.
Question
Given a normalized $k\times{n}$ Latin rectangle $R$, how many $(k+1)\times{n}$ Latin rectangles can be constructed by extending the original rectangle by a single row?
Followup: Let's call this number of possible 1-row extensions from a $k\times{n}$ Latin rectangle $R$, as $E_1[R_{k\times{n}}]$. Specifically for $k=2$, what properties of the permutation that appears on the 2nd row of $R_{2\times{n}}$ determine $E_1[R_{2\times{n}}]$?
Additional Information
Some special cases are easy to calculate.

If $k=1$, then the only option is $R_{1\times{n}}=[0,\dots,n-1]$ and therefore $E_1[R_{1\times{n}}]$ is equal to number of possible normalized $2\times{n}$ Latin rectangles. This is equal to $D_n$, the number of derangements of $0,1,\dots,n-1$. Therefore:
$$E_1[R_{1\times{n}}]=D_n=n!\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$
If $k=n-1$, then $E_1[R_{(n-1)\times{n}}]=1$, since there is a unique way of picking the symbol in each column of the final row to form a Latin square.

I am primarily interested in the case when $k=2$, i.e how many ways there are to extend a specific two-row Latin square to a third row. According to my numerical simulations the number of extensions depends on the properties of the permutation that appears on the 2nd row. That is to say, in general, two normalized $2\times{n}$ Latin rectangles have different number of extensions to $3\times{n}$ Latin rectangles.
For $k=2$, the number of cycles and the order of the 2nd row permutation appear to be enough to determine the number of extensions (up to $n=8$), but I don't have a proof that these two properties are enough to determine the number of extensions for general $n$.
While the assumption that the number of extensions is independent of the $2 \times n$ table is incorrect for $n \gt 3$, it is still useful in finding the average number of options in the 3rd row. Let's call the number of normalized $k\times{n}$ Latin rectangles $K(k,n)$. Then $K(k=3,n)$ should be equal to $K(k=2,n)$ multiplied by the expected number of associated possible extensions to a third row, i.e.
$$\mathbb{E}_R\left[E_1[R_{2\times{n}}]\right]=\dfrac{K(k=3,n)}{K(k=2,n)}$$
Formulas for $K(k=3,n)$ for arbitrary $n$ can be found in Stones 2010. The expected numbers that one gets for extensions from two to three rows are:



n
$\mathbb{E}_R\left[E_1[R_{2\times{n}}]\right]$




4
8/3


5
12.54545454545454


6
80.30188679245283


7
579.15857605178


8
4739.382727701746



These match precisely the average results that I am getting from enumerating all the possible Latin rectangles up to $n=8$.
Below are the results of my simulations for the pure counts for $k=2$. It is interesting that all $E_1$ counts are very close to the expected values $\mathbb{E}_R\left[E_1[R]\right]$. I have included the permutation order and number of cycles for the 2nd row of the R matrix. I cannot find a general pattern.
k=2, n=4




2nd row's permutation_order
2nd row's permutation_cycles
$E_1[R_{2\times{4}}]$
occurrences




0
2
2
4
3


1
4
1
2
6



k=2, n=5




2nd row's permutation_order
2nd row's permutation_cycles
$E_1[R_{2\times{5}}]$
occurrences




0
5
1
13
24


1
6
2
12
20



k=2, n=6




2nd row's permutation_order
2nd row's permutation_cycles
$E_1[R_{2\times{6}}]$
occurrences




0
2
3
80
15


1
3
2
82
40


2
4
2
80
90


3
6
1
80
120



k=2, n=7




2nd row's permutation_order
2nd row's permutation_cycles
$E_1[R_{2\times{7}}]$
occurrences




0
6
3
580
210


1
7
1
579
720


2
10
2
580
504


3
12
2
578
420



k=2, n=8




2nd row's permutation_order
2nd row's permutation_cycles
$E_1[R_{2\times{8}}]$
occurrences




0
2
4
4752
105


1
4
2
4740
1260


2
4
3
4744
1260


3
6
2
4740
3360


4
6
3
4740
1120


5
8
1
4738
5040


6
15
2
4738
2688



